# WebSocket connection failed (Django channels)

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to establish a websocket connection, however, I'm getting this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://oasis.yiaap.com/ws/question/aaass-bc6f6f2e-4a96-4174-a8dd-a3b8f03645a7/' failed:
```

I think everything is set up correctly.

```
#routes.py
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    #re_path(r"ws/questions/", consumers.QuestionsConsumer.as_asgi()),
    path("ws/question/<question_slug>/", consumers.QuestionConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

```
#consumers.py
class QuestionConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        #print("DEBUG")
        self.question_slug = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['question_slug']
        self.room_name = self.question_slug
        self.room_group_name = 'question_%s' % self.room_name

        # In order to detect who is the owner of the room
        # We'll setup the user

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

        # Check if the question exists in the database otherwise close the connection
        # and send a message says 'question not found' so client can act on it
        is_questions_exists = await questions_exists(question_slug=self.question_slug)
        if is_questions_exists == False:
            await self.send_json({"message": "question_not_found"})
            await self.close()
            await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
                self.room_group_name,
                self.channel_name
            )

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        user_id = self.scope["client"][1]
        owner_user_id = cache.get(f"{self.room_name}_owner")

        if user_id == owner_user_id:
            # Check if the user is the question owner then delete the question from database
            await delete_question(self.question_slug)
            cache.delete_pattern(f"{self.room_name}_owner")

            # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive answer from WebSocket

    async def receive_json(self, content):
        answer = content.get('answer', None)
        is_owner = content.get("is_owner", None)
        if answer:
            # Send answer to room group
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.room_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'question_answer',
                    'answer': answer
                }
            )
        elif is_owner:
            # Set a websocket client port as user id in cache
            user_id = self.scope["client"][1]
            cache.set(f"{self.room_name}_owner", user_id)

    # Receive answer from room group

    async def question_answer(self, event):
        answer = event['answer']
        # Send answer to WebSocket
        await self.send_json({
            'answer': answer
        })
```

```
#asgi.py
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": 
        URLRouter(
            websocket_urlpatterns
    )
})
```

```
//this is in react, however, I think everything is okay here
const wsfunc = () => {
            // Subscribe to anychanges to `questions` in the backend/database
            const ws = new WebSocket(
                `${HOST_WEBSOCKET_URL}question/${question_data.slug}/`
            )
            ws.onopen = (e) => {
                ws.onmessage = (e) => {
                    const data = JSON.parse(e.data)
                    if (data) {
                        switch (data.message) {
                            case "question_not_found":
                                router.push("/")
                                break
                            default:
                                console.log(data)
                                setAnswers((state) => [data.answer, ...state])
                                break
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Send a message and say I am the owner
                ws.send(
                    JSON.stringify({
                        is_owner: true,
                    })
                )
                ws.onclose = () => {
                    window.location.href = "/"
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried adding a debug message in consumers.py on connect, but it doesn't get triggered, so probably something is wrong before that.

I'm not really an expert on websockets, in fact this is my first time using it.
Basically, I can't establish a websocket connection.

EDIT:
this is in production server. Also, I'm using Daphne and Nginx

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your normal website work? If I visit oasis.yiaap.com  I still get an nginx 404 error. EDIT: I see now that it's working but ,you have CORS errors.

Comment: @EPaul, that's because you are trying with http rather than https, but you won't be able to connect because I have password protection setup in nginx. 
But, website is working normally.